# Convert code for 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of images which I need to download on my folder and renamed. I have tried the macro below but it is not working on 32bit excel please help me work on 64 bit.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Dim Ret As Long

'~~> This is where the images will be saved. Change as applicable
Const FolderName As String = "C:\Temp\"

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim strPath As String

    '~~> Name of the sheet which has the list
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow '<~~ 2 because row 1 has headers
        strPath = FolderName & ws.Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"

        Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, ws.Range("B" & i).Value, strPath, 0, 0)

        If Ret = 0 Then
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "File successfully downloaded"
        Else
            ws.Range("C" & i).Value = "Unable to download the file"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if it's part of something bigger, but you can use [IRFanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) to rename and resize images in bulk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want an imported function that works with both 32-bit and 64-bit, you need to use compiler directives in the declaration.

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
      Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr _
      ) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "Wininet.dll" _
      Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" ( _
        ByVal lpszUrlName As String _
      ) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
      Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
        ByVal pCaller As Long, _
        ByVal szURL As String, _
        ByVal szFileName As String, _
        ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
        ByVal lpfnCB As Long _
      ) As Long
    Private Declare Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "Wininet.dll" _
      Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" ( _
        ByVal lpszUrlName As String _
      ) As Long
#End If

Public Const ERROR_SUCCESS As Long = 0
Public Const BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION As Long = &H10
Public Const INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD As Long = &H80000000
Public Const folderName As String = "c:\temp\"

Sub downloadImages()
    Dim i As Long, ret As Long, sWAN As String, sLAN As String
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            sLAN = folderName & .Cells(i, 1).Value & ".jpg"
            sWAN = .Cells(i, 2).Value

            ret = URLDownloadToFile(0&, sWAN, sLAN, BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION, 0&)
            
            If ret = 0 Then
                .Cells(i, 3) = "File successfully downloaded"
            Else
                .Cells(i, 3) = "Unable to download the file"
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
End Sub
```

The `#If VBA7 And Win64 Then` tells VBA how to compile the imported function(s). 64-bit versions use `PtrSafe`. The above was tested on both 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: Hi and good day,, thank you so much i really appreciate it,,this is perfect now i can my my job easy..cheers

Comment: this work on me but it hangs a lot and i cannot work on excel,,any suggestion please?

Comment: please disregard my previous comment it is working now i just remove the declaration for 32bit thank you

Comment: Note that you [don't need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57843773/11683) to use `Win64`.